# jQuery show and/or hide element based on set date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, setinterval

I am trying to show a button called 'oecard' when a saved start time has been reached, and then hide it once the saved end time has been reached.

```
var db_st = item.DB_ST; // saved in db as '2017-10-02 12:20:00 PM'
var db_et = item.DB_ET; // saved in db as '2017-10-02 12:25:00 PM'

var cd_start = new Date(db_st).getTime(); // converts db date to milliseconds
var cd_end = new Date(db_et).getTime(); // converts db date to milliseconds

var currentdate = $.now();

var loop = setInterval(function(){
  if(currentdate >= cd_start && currentdate <= cd_end) 
  {
    $('#oecard').show();
  }
  else
  {
    $('#oecard').hide();
  }
},1);
```

I attempted the above code to no avail.  The button does not appear on the saved time, but when I refresh the page, it does.  Same thing happens with the end time.

I know this has to be some kind of logic error.  I need to do this dynamically without having to refresh the page.

Comment: Try moving `var currentdate = $.now();` inside `setInterval`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put `currentdate` inside your loop:

```
var loop = setInterval(function(){
  var currentdate = $.now();

  if(currentdate >= cd_start && currentdate <= cd_end) 
  {
    $('#oecard').show();
  }
  else
  {
    $('#oecard').hide();
  }
},1);
```

The value returned by $.now() is not dynamic, it will not update for you, you'll need to call it every time your `setInterval` callback is called.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `Date.parse` for comparing dates. Eg

```
Date.parse('01/01/2011 10:20:45') > Date.parse('01/01/2011 5:10:10')
//true
```

Use `custom events` for listening to time for doing things without refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the code in few lines using [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display) like:

```
setInterval(function(){
   $('#oecard').toggle($.now() >= cd_start && $.now() <= cd_end);
}, 1);
```